# Why should I use Runnable instead of Thread?

Tags: java

I just learn the theory about thread. And there is Thread and Runnable.

```
class A extends Thread{
    public void run(){
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Hi");
            }           
        }
    }
```

---

```
class B implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Thread is good with rich API, so why would I use Runnable instead of Thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, which means you can only extend one Java class, so once you extended `Thread` class you lost your chance and cannot extend (inherit) another class in Java.
2. In OOP, extending a class generally means adding new functionality, modifying or improve behaviors. If you are not making any modification on `Thread`, then use `Runnable` interface instead.
3. Implementing `Runnable` makes your class more flexible (you can implement more than one interface).

Comment: In what situation would you want to implement Runnable and extend something else at the same time? (and where the superclass is one that couldn't extend Thread itself)

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Just think we need JFrame qualities in class, then we have to extends JFrame, to get that. In same class if we need to get thread(concurrently process) qualities we have to implement Runnable. Because we cannot extends from Thread(We already inherited one class). Hope you understand. @immibis :)

Comment: @DhanukaLakshan Most people would recommend not extending JFrame for the same reasons you shouldn't extend Thread. So you can decide whether those are good reasons or not :)

Comment: Yes! you're correct. Thankyou @immibis for point that out. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

One of the big advantages is: you don't have to run a `Runnable` on a new thread.

One day, you might decide that instead of running it on a new thread, you should run it directly (on the current thread), or on a thread pool - and then you can change `new Thread(runnable).start()` to `threadPool.submit(runnable)` or `runnable.run()` - and the change only affects one place.

Also, if you leave a `Runnable` hanging around, it doesn't waste resources - it doesn't count towards the thread limit (if there is one), and it doesn't reserve space for a stack. Say you wanted to have a queue of things to do one at a time - sure, you could have a `Queue<Thread>` and then start each thread when the previous one finished, but then you're wasting a lot of memory with non-running threads. If you used a queue of `Runnable`s, you don't use as much memory except when they're actually running.

Comment: (ELI5 version: a Thread is "a worker", a Runnable is "some work". Sure, you could have a bunch of workers that only do one thing each, but that's inefficient, isn't it?)