# Thread with runnable vs without runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Could you please give a short explanation of whether there is a significant difference between the following thread implementations:

```
// Method 1
Thread aThread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // do some work
    }
};

aThread.start();

// Method 2      
Thread bThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // do some work
    }
});

bThread.start();
```

I tried to find similar questions in stackoverflow, but couldn't succeed. Sorry, if it is already discussed before.

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871073/java-thread-vs-runnable

Comment: @MarkW , Please read the links I posted before making a comment. Here is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15226278/950427 from the links I provided.

Comment: Jared Burrows, thank you for your comments, but I don't find them the same as my example. At least because I use threads in both methods, but in your methods - one is Thread and another one is Runnable.

Comment: and another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553051/why-should-i-use-runnable-instead-of-thread

Comment: There's no difference at all. Actually, both apporaches are equally bad practise. You should use an `Executor` or `ExecutorService` instead.

Comment: Jared Burrows, please explain why it is the same?
 Federico Peralta Schaffner, thank you for your answer. But could you please explain why it is bad practise?

Comment: @SaQada https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html `Executor` abstracts away the details of `Thread` creation and management.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, I've never seen a use-case for `Executor`, but `ExecutorService` is an interface for a _thread pool_.  Thread pools have their uses, but they are not a silver bullet that solves all threading problems.  (Hint:  If `ExecutorService` solves all problems, then why did they also give us `ThreadFactory`?)  I would not use a thread _pool_ in cases where I want a single `Thread` that runs for the entire lifetime of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--

the default `run()` method of `Thread` executes the `run()` method of the `Runnable` it was created with, if it exists.  Otherwise it does nothing.  What this means is that creating a `Thread` with a `Runnable` does the same thing as overriding `Thread`'s `run()`, except it uses slightly more stack for the additional function call.

So no.  No significant difference.

Comment: If you are going to say, `As per the Javadoc`, be sure to actually include a link.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Done.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I did not down vote you, but this is a duplicate question anyways.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  It was a good suggestion anyway.

Comment: Tripp Kinetics, thank you for your answer, I upvoted it. I need to search a bit in google to read about what you wrote regarding stack.

Comment: If my answer was useful, please accept it.

Comment: @Tripp Kinetics, it was, thank you :)